# Ext.create always returns Objects of the class "Ext.Class.newClass"

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to create Ext objects with "Ext.create" the Extjs version i'm using is 4.0.7 (updating would cause a lot of work i'm trying to avoid because the (css) skins for ie would need to be regenerated and tested).

Somehow everytime i try to create an Object of a specific type i.e. `Ext.store.JsonStore` with

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {...config here...});
```

i get back an object of the type `Ext.class.newClass` without an error beeing thrown.

Does anyone know what can generally cause this problem? Or is this just the usual case and there will be no objects returned of the given type? I know that this is very little information but unfortuantelly even after a lot of research on the web and in the sourcode this is everything i have.

Comment: Have you tried just creating a Ext.data.Store and setting it's proxy to have a reader that returns json as per example in their docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store? According to the docs JsonStore is a private class, which I'm guessing may also cause some issues.

Comment: That was just an example. This happens with absolutely all classes i'm trying to create.

Comment: What is happening that makes you think there is a problem?  Is it just the console saying that `Ext.class.newClass` is what your new object is, or are you actually not able to call any of the member functions of your new item?

Comment: Its actually only the console displaying that which makes it hard to tell what object i'm expecting.